# loop inside Model.new in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I know it's a very short question. I understand "{ }" represents a loop.
and the new operator creates a new active record object.

What does this line do in rails?  from where does lead come?

```
Proc.new{|lead| lead.lead_details.name}
```

Comment: It's neither a loop nor a Rails model. What you have is a Ruby [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Proc.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates new `Proc` object. `lead` doest't come from anywhere in this example since this `Proc` doesn't get called. But you can call that, passing it as a block, for example.

```
leads = Lead.includes(:lead_details) # I assume it's an AR model, obviously
p = Proc.new { |lead| lead.lead_details.name }
names = leads.map(&p)
```

This way, `lead` comes from `map` method and represent single element of `leads` array-like object, it's equivalent to this:

```
leads.map { |lead| lead.lead_details.name }
```

You can also call this procedure 'by hand', passing argument explicitly, like this:

```
p.call(leads.first)
# => Whatever is leads.first.lead_details.name
```

You can even write your own method using it as block, for example:

```
def first_do(collection)
  yield(collection.first)
end
first_do(leads, &p)
# => Whatever is leads.first.lead_details.name
```